# I want vscode extension for automatically complete path in vscode

Tags: url, next.js, path, background-image, vscode-extensions

I'm using tailwind on vscode, and I'm writing a style like bg-[url(")] this. But the image path isn't completed automatically.[image: tailwind style code]

Is there an vscode extension that automatically completes a path when entering it within url('')? FYI, if it's not url() format, the route is automatically completed!

Answer (score 0):

As I researched some path extensions for VSCode, found that there is no such type of autocomplete path url extension for tailwind `bg-[url('')]` CSS. So, You could install the below extensions, and it also does the same work!

- Path Intellisense
- Path Autocomplete

I hope this helps.